# C programming 2D array memory layout

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

Consider the c code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6},
                       {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
   printf("%u, %u, %u", x+3, *(x+3), *(x+2)+3);
   printf("\n%u, %u, %u", x,&x,*x);
   return 0;
}
```

Now each of the printf statement prints the same values as mentioned below.

```
6356724, 6356724, 6356724
6356688, 6356688, 6356688
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.128 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I wanted to know how is the outcome same in each printf statements. 
This is my understanding of memory layout of 2-D array.
[image: 2-D array memory layout]

Now I believe x+3 refers to base address of( x + 3 * size require for pointer arithmetic ) = 24 
and *(x +3 ) = *(24) = 2036 but its not the case the first printf statement prints 2036, 2036 2036 . I wanted to visually understand how exactly 2-D array is organized.

Comment: use %p not %u if you try to print a pointer value

Comment: @Eraklon its prints the address in hexadecimal format as : 0060FEF4, 0060FEF4,0060FEF4
0060FED0, 0060FED0, 0060FED0
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.119 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: `x + 3` is same as `x[3]` which is also same as`*(x + 3)`. `*(x + 2) + 3` is `x[2] + 3` since the array is 3 wide therefore this addition return essentially `x[3]`. Your understanding of the memory layout though seems correct given that int is 4 byte size on the machine. The confusion came from the pointer arithmetics.

Comment: @Eraklon "`x + 3` is the same as `x[3]`" ???

Comment: The behaviour of this code is undefined. It can print absolutely anything, or nothing at all, or melt your hard disk.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yepp its misleading sry. I mean address wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain from a layman's point of view.

**Let us assume the base address is 3000, and assume that integer takes 4 bytes.**

Considering your 2-D array, this is how WE visualise a 2-D array in the memory :

```
         0                       1                2
     --------------------------------------------------
  0 |   1                |    2           |   3          |
    | 3000/3001/3002/3003| 3004/05/06/07  | 3008/09/10/11|
    |___________________ |________________|______________|                      
  1 |    4               |    5           |   6          |
    |   3012             |    3016        |   3020       |
    |____________________|________________|______________|                      
  2 |    7               |    8           |   9          |
    |    3024            |    3028        |   3032       |
    |____________________|________________|______________|                      
  3 |     10             |   11           |   12         |
    |    3036            |   3040         |   3044       |
    |                    |                |              |
    ------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, you should know how a 2-D array is actually stored just like a 1-D array in the memory:

```
index    0       1       2      3     4      5     6      7      8      9      10    11  

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   | 6   |  7   |  8   |  9   |  10  |  11 |  12  |       
       |      |      |      |      |      |     |      |      |      |      |     |      |
add.   |3000__|_3004_|_3008_|_3012_|_3016_|_3020|3024__|_3028_|3032__|_3036_|_3040|3044_ |
```

---

Now, your code says:

```
printf("%u, %u, %u", x+3, *(x+3), *(x+2)+3);
```

**(i) x+3**

Here x is your base address, which is 3000(assumed), and +3 means the 3rd row. Since there is nothing after that,i.e, x+3, we will find out the address of the first element of the 3rd row.

=3000+36=3036

*(refer the 2D array visualisation that WE see, the first one)*

**(ii) *(x+3)**

This is the same as x+3, i.e, we have to find the address of the first element of the third row. I say the first element because if something was mentioned after *(x+3)+'something', then we would be concerned about finding it.

=3000+36=3036.

*(refer the 2D array visualisation that WE see, the first one)*

**(iii) *(x+2)+3**

**Just for understanding**, let us break this into two parts.

First, *(x+2): as we have seen in the above two parts, *(x+2) says that "I  have started from the base address, now give me the address of the first element of the 2nd row. **So, we reach element with value 7 and address 3024**. *(refer the 2D array visualisation that WE see, the first one)*

Second, +3 as in *(x+2)+3 means that since we have reached element with value 7 and address 3024, **now see/move to the 3rd element** after the element with value 7 and address 3024 (where we are right now). So, we move past/see-through elements with values 8 and 9, with addresses 3028 and 3032 respectively, and reach/land on the element with value 10 and address

=3000+36=3036

*(refer the 2D array visualisation that WE see, the first one)*

---

---

For your second code:

```
 printf("\n%u, %u, %u", x,&x,*x);
```

I go with @[n. 'pronouns' m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-pronouns-m) answer.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever an array is mentioned, it [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to a pointer to its first element (except in a few cases that are not interesting right now).

Why `x`, `&x` and `*x` are all printed the same? That's because the array itself, its first element, (and if it's a 2D array, the first element of its first element, which is by itself a 1D array) all have the same address.

So:

- `&x` is the pointer to the array
- `x` is the array itself, which decays to the pointer of its first element
- `*x` is the first element of the array, which is itself an array `(1, 2, 3}`, so it decays to the pointer of *its* first element

All these pointers have different types, but point to the same address.

The same thing happens with `x+3` and `*(x+3)`. First, `x` decays to a pointer, then pointer arithmetic is performed. Say `y = x + 3`, so `y` and `*y` point to the same address just as `x` and *x` do (see above).

What about `*(x+2)+3`? Well, `*(x + 2)` is itself is an array of 3 elements. So `*(x+2)+3` points to one element *past the end* of the `*(x + 2)` array. This non-existing element [has an address nevertheless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472531/what-is-the-rationale-for-one-past-the-last-element-of-an-array-object), and it is the same as the address of the first element of the `*(x + 3)` array --- because `*(x + 2)` and `*(x + 3)` are next to each other in the `x` array.